# How to classify an image according to two other given images

Tags: python, image, opencv

I am trying to identify a state of a valve(on or off). My approach is to give to images of each states and compare the current image with those two and see which one it belongs to.

I have tried to compare using `new_image - on_image` and `new_image - off_image`. Then compare the number of different pixels. It works, but i feel like in some cases it might not work and there must be another better way do a simple classification like this.

[image]

Any reference or ideas?

Comment: Please provide your code and sample images for better understanding.

Comment: Rest of the code is just opening images and stuff, all i did is subtract the numpy arrays of the images.

Comment: @Eshaka Even if it is just subtraction, the other images are required to help you find a better classification. You shouldn't expect us to suggest an answer to a classification problem with one image.

Comment: @RickM. for now this is the only image i have. the other state of this image is a Photoshoped image from this one. but the images that need to be classified will also be taken by this same camera and the camera is fixed. so the photos will be almost the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subtracting pixels might not be very robust in case your camera position changes slightly. If you don't shy away from using [open Computer Vision](https://opencv.org/) (open CV) there is an interesting recipe for finding a predefined object in a picture:

[Feature Matching + Homography to find Objects](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_feature_homography/py_feature_homography.html#py-feature-homography)

You could cut out the lever from your image and search it in every new image. Depending on the coordinates and especially the rotation, you can set the status of the valve. This might even work in crazy cases where someone half opened (or for pessimists: half closed) the valve, or if the lever becomes partially covered.